# How to rename a String variable dynamically using javassist?

Tags: reflection, javassist

I have a class named `Sample` and I need to rename the variable `messageID` to `NameID`, such that the corresponding getter and setter are also updated.

```
public class Sample{

    String messageID;

    public String getMessageID() {
        return MessageID;
    }

    public void setMessageID(String messageID) {
        MessageID = messageID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Javassist you can **change the field name and all the references** from old field name to the new one.

```
  ClassPool classpool = ClassPool.getDefault();
  CtClass ctClass = classpool.get(Sample.class.getName());
  CtField field = ctClass.getField("messageID");
  CodeConverter codeConverter = new CodeConverter();
  codeConverter.redirectFieldAccess(field, ctClass, "NameID");
  ctClass.instrument(codeConverter);
  field.setName("NameID");
```

If you don't know ho to use `Javassist` you should read this tutorial [here](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html) 
The trick about "rewiring" all field references is done using a `CodeConverter` that will replace all references to the `CtField` field for the references to the field named `NameID` in `ctClass`. Keep in mind that this needs to be done before renaming the field into `NameID`.

However you should remember that all the references are updated but the set/get methods names are still `getMessageID` and `setMessageID`. You can easily change that using the same reference of `ctClass` as follow:

```
CtMethod getter = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMessageID");
getter.setName("getNameId");
CtMethod setter = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMessageID");
setter.setName("setNameId");
```